# Swing - Change table model reset the renderer. Why?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

My SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Renderer_Model_LookAndFeel extends JFrame {
    public Renderer_Model_LookAndFeel() {
        begin();
    }

    private void begin() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new NimbusLookAndFeel());
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        Object[][] data = new Object[4][4];
        Object[] title = new Object[] {"Name", "Gender", "Age", "Prof."};

        JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data, title));

        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
                data[i][j] = "Tom"; 
            }
        }


        //SET RENDERER
        DefaultTableCellRenderer r = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        r.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(r);

        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, title));

        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 300));

        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);
        sp.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 400);
        getContentPane().add(sp);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Renderer_Model_LookAndFeel frame = new Renderer_Model_LookAndFeel();

            }

        });
    }
}
```

The key is in the order of these lines:

```
table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, title));
```

And:

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer r = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
r.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(r);
```

If I first set the model and then change the column renderer, the third column will be right-aligned. But, if I set the renderer first and then change model, the renderer will be reset to `null` and then, respects the default alignment.

Why?

In my project we first establish the UI part in method A, and then read a XML file to fill the data in method B, in order to separate the data with the UI presentation. So, I do it in this order:

1. Construct all the UI components, including the table, fill it with an empty data vector;
2. Read the XML to get the data.
3. Reset the table data.

So the problem occurs. I have no problem switching the order (although it mixes the data part with UI), but I just want to know the reason.

Comment: why would you set a `new DefaultTableModel` 2 times? i would guess because you override the given model , which the renderer worked with and then it becomes null. set the model at initialization of the table and never again after

Comment: This is actually what `setModel` does

Comment: Well it is what should be like I guess. I added more details.

Comment: create a DefaultTableModel and work with it all the time and add data to the model with `model.addRow()`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer ye it's the way it should be.. and more clear because yes, we work with rows.

Comment: And @MadProgrammer, so some details?

Comment: @FaithReaper setting of the new table model causes recreation of the column model. You can turn it off using the method `JTable.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(boolean)`, but in this case you need to install the column model by yourself.

Comment: `JTabel#setModel` calls `tableChanged`, this in turn, but default, calls `createDefaultColumnsFromModel`, this is, in part, what's changing the cell renderer, as it creates all new `TableColumn`s - solution, don't set the renderer against the column, but set it against the column type by calling `JTable#setDefaultRenderer`, passing in the `Class` type of the column which is returned by `TableModel#getColumnClass`. Personally, I'd avoid `setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel` because it introduces a considerable amount of overhead and could cause a lot of problems if it gets out of sync, but that's me